# Why am I getting a 404 requested resource not available error from Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat7

I have recreated this project in Eclipse as many ways as I can think of and continue to get this same error-

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SpringTest/hello 

    type Status report

    message /SpringTest/hello

    description The requested resource (/SpringTest/hello) is not available.
```

Please help me find the issue in my code below.

web.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Controller -

```
package net.viralpatel.spring3.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

index.jsp -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Index - ViralPatel.net</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="hello">Say Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

hello.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Hello World - ViralPatel.net</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

.classpath -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Tomcat">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

.project -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
<name>SpringTest</name>
<comment></comment>
<projects>
</projects>
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
</natures>
</projectDescription>
```

My Project -

[image: My Project Explorer]

Eclipse console output -

```
May 21, 2011 10:28:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/glassfish3/jdk/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/glassfish3/jdk/bin/../jre/bin;C:/glassfish3/jdk/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin;C:\eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32\eclipse;
May 21, 2011 10:28:11 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringTest' did not find a matching property.
May 21, 2011 10:28:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 21, 2011 10:28:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 21, 2011 10:28:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 425 ms
May 21, 2011 10:28:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 21, 2011 10:28:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.14
May 21, 2011 10:28:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
May 21, 2011 10:28:11 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
May 21, 2011 10:28:11 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Sat May 21 22:28:11 CDT 2011]; root of context hierarchy
May 21, 2011 10:28:11 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
May 21, 2011 10:28:12 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1e1ec86: defining beans [helloWorldController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,viewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
May 21, 2011 10:28:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
May 21, 2011 10:28:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello.*] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
May 21, 2011 10:28:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello/] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
May 21, 2011 10:28:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 545 ms
May 21, 2011 10:28:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 21, 2011 10:28:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 21, 2011 10:28:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1139 ms
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed question.  I was looking for help with a directory layout problem and seeing your layout helped me fix it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your `web.xml` only maps `*.html` requests to your servlet, and you are sending it a request without a `.html` suffix.

One solution is to change the servlet mapping.  For example

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

matches any suffix, or

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

matches any path.

Comment: This throws  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> * in servlet mapping` . Any clue?

Comment: Ah yes.  That should be "/*"

Answer (score 1):

As @Stephen suggested change the `url pattern`

OR

Call the controller from you `index.jsp` as `hello.html`